# Reference error: function name is not defined

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Trying to get my two function to run through a button in html using `onclick="beginFunction();"` however I get an error saying the function beginFunction() isn't defined. Don't really know what's wrong or how to fix it!

```
        function(randomText){
       var count = 0,
      wordsArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4", "Text 5", "Text 6"];
      setInterval(function () {
        count++;
        $(".first").fadeOut(400, function () {
          $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
        });
      }, 8000);

    };


         function displayNextImage() {
                  x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
                  document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
              }

              function displayPreviousImage() {
                  x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
                  document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
              }

              function startTimer() {
                  setInterval(displayNextImage, 8000);
              }

              var images = [], x = -1;
              images[0] = "img/question-2.png";
              images[1] = "img/question-3.png";
              images[2] = "img/question-4.png";
              images[3] = "img/question-5.png";
              images[4] = "img/question-6.png";

                       function beginFunction(){  
           startTimer(); 
           randomText();
        }
```

Comment: It's in an external js file defined? Do you have other errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change like this. `Javascript` function declaration was wrong

**change From**

```
function(randomText){}
```

**to**

```
function randomText(){}
```

Change like this

```
    function randomText(){
   var count = 0,
  wordsArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4", "Text 5", "Text 6"];
  setInterval(function () {
    count++;
    $(".first").fadeOut(400, function () {
      $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
    });
  }, 8000);

};
```

See the below snippet .How the append?

```js
function beginFunction() {
  randomText();
}
function(randomText){}
```

```html
<button onclick="beginFunction()">change</button>
```

Comment: the error is gone. thanks. however beginFunction() doesn't run both function - only runs the startTimer() function when clicked, not the randomText().

Comment: Are you running the code with my update?.put some `alert('hi')` function in `randomText()` .check the alert is showing or not?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Developer Tools in your browser. Look at the error messages. Deal with the **first** error first.

The first function declaration in the file is missing its *name*, this is a syntax error which causes the parsing of the file to abort so none of the functions are created.